# ADE types singularities of $K3$ surfaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, surfaces, k3-surfaces

I was reading a paper in which they have an algebraic surface
\begin{equation}
F(x, y, u) = u^2(1+xy)= (x+y).(x+y-4xy+x^2y+xy^2)
\end{equation}
After homogenising the surface they get;
\begin{equation}
F(x, y, u,z) = u^2(z^2+xy)-(x+y).((x+y)z^2-4xyz+x^2y+xy^2)
\end{equation}
They are saying one of the singularities of this projective hypersurface is $[x:y:u:z] = [1:1:0:1]$
and this singularity is ADE type $A_1$.

I have found on the internet so far that to prove it $A_1$ type; I have to show that the singular point is analytic isomorphic to
\begin{equation}
x^2+y^2+z^2 =0
\end{equation}
Can someone please explain how I can show that? I would be a great help if you explain the steps for the calculation in simpler words as I don't have much mathematical background knowledge in this area.

Comment: You need to compute the Taylor expansion at the singular point. Basically there should be no linear terms and three (out of a maximum of four) quadratic terms.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for your reply. Up to what order I have to do the expansion? Only order 2?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @TabesBridges Hi! Thanks again. What if I don't know the type of singularity in the beginning. In that case, how I come to know up to what order, I have to do the Taylor expansion.

Comment: I'm not a singularities person really, but I think it comes down to writing out terms until you get something that looks like one of the equations in the classification (at least for ADE singularities).

Comment: @TabesBridges Okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Although I am late to the party, let me provide an answer for those who encounter this question in the future and want to know the answer.

We don't need the homogeneous form of the equation, but it is useful to change coordinates so that the singular point is at the origin. Let us therefore put $v=x-1$, $w=y-1$. A short calculation will show that the new equation of the surface is
$$
u^2(vw+v+w+2)=(v+w+2)(v^2w+vw^2+v^2+w^2).
$$
(If we ignore terms of degree $3$ and higher, this reads $2u^2 = 2v^2+2w^2$, showing that we are on the right track, but we won't use this further.) Now assuming the characteristic of the base field is $0$ (or probably different from $2$ is good enough), the element
$$
a = \frac{vw+v+w+2}{v+w+2} = \frac{1+v/2+w/2+vw/2}{1+v/2+w/2}
$$
is an invertible power series; it is even the square of such a power series, which we shall call $\alpha$, so that $\alpha^2=a$, since we can just use the binomial theorem $(1+X)^{1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{n} X^n$ for both the numerator and the denominator. Hence, putting $u'=\alpha u$, we get that the equation of the surface is analytically isomorphic to
$$
(u')^2 = v^2w+vw^2+v^2+w^2
$$
in the neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$. So now we just need to get rid of the terms $v^2w$ and $vw^2$, and we are done.

Likewise as in the construction of $\alpha$, there are invertible power series $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $\beta^2=1+v$ and $\gamma^2=1+w$. Letting $v'=\gamma v$ and $w' = \beta w$, we end up with
$$
(u')^2 = (v')^2 + (w')^2,
$$
which shows that we are in the case of an $\textrm{A}_1$ singularity.